# Access JS object inside jquery each() iterator function

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

```
$('input.ISSelectSearch').each(function(i) {
    var box = new Object;
    box.size = 80;
    box.width = 110;
    //CODE CODE CODE
});
```

How can I access the value of `box` which was set in the previous iteration? Alternatively, is it possible to access it via a key of some kind?

```
$('input.ISSelectSearch').each(function(i) {
    var box = new Object;
    box.size = 80;
    box.width = 110;
    prevsize = $(this).box[/* previous iteration element id or name */].size
    //CODE CODE CODE
});
```

The problem is that I need to know the data associated with each `'input.ISSelectSearch'` element box so that I can change them depending on the values of the current or preceding box objects. In other words I need a connection between the element box objects so that I can specify certain changes in one based on the values of another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
var pre = null;
$('input.ISSelectSearch').each(function(i) {
    var box = new Object;
    box.size = 80;
    box.width = 110;
    //condition so that first time it dosent shows an error
    if(pre!=null){
     //CODE

    }
    pre = this;
    //CODE CODE CODE
});
```

EDIT AFTER THE COMMENT:-
probably you wanna use $.data() method
this was you can associate the data with the element
so inside the loop you can do

```
$('input.ISSelectSearch').each(function(i) {
    var box = new Object;
    box.size = 80;
    box.width = 110;
    $('input.ISSelectSearch').data(i,box);
    //and now you can retrive the data whenevr you want
    var olderObject = $('input.ISSelectSearch').data(SOME_OLDER_INDEX)
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that you want the condition pre!=null ? On which iteration will it be not null?

Comment: I guess you want the `pre=this`outside the if

Comment: Ok and if I have 5 elements in each loop and for example I need access 1fst element box object properties from the 3rd element. I don't want to use any global variables like pre. Maybe there is some manipulation methods that could access all stored box objects in memory. I think JS and jquery somehow stores them into the memory or in etc shared storage

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with index if you like

```
var $This = $('input.ISSelectSearch');
$This.each(function (index, value) {
  var Pre;
  var box = { size: 80, width: 110 };
  if (index > 0) {
    Pre = $This[index - 1];
    //Your code hear
  } else {
    //otherwise
  }
});
```